# Booting Windows from GRUB rescue

Tags: linux, xubuntu

I tried installed Xubuntu via YUMI and I restarted my PC – the GUI for YUMI came up and I tried to carry on the installation by tabbing down to 'Linux Distributions' and there was nothing ahead but just to go back. From here I'm stuck.

I've tried booting Windows using GRUB, but I tried:

- `ls (hd0)`
- `ls (hd0,0)`, etc.

and I just carry on getting 'Unknown filesystem type'.

There is only one (fd0) which I don't get that error, and I get a read error message.

I tried installing using a partition on my hard drive, and multi-booting side by side with Windows. So Windows is still installed, but I can't seem to find anywhere to boot it. On the boot menu (<kbd>F11</kbd> on startup) I get my main hard drive and my external hard drive.

I'm lost on how to get back into Windows – I don't have the installation disk, and, additionally, my DVD drive isn't fully functional. The only thing I have is a laptop and external hard drive, which I can think I can use to my advantage.

Answer (score 0):

You can borrow your friend PC with windows installed and create `Windows Usb Recovery-Drive` (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive).